# Is Is there a limit to "hours" variable in everyHours(n) statement?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a limit to the "hours" (the "(n)") variable in the "everyHours(n)" time-based trigger in Google Apps Script?

Comment: If you mean whether the number of hours can be more than 24, I don't know.  You'd need to test it.  You can't enter fractions of hours, I don't believe.  You can't enter something smaller than an hour.

Comment: I meant something like 256 hours, to create a 2-week trigger.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  You could have a weekly trigger that is set up to run the day before the two weeks is up, and then that trigger creates an hourly trigger than runs every hour starting on the day before you want the code to actually run.  The code that runs every hour will need to check the current hour and then run or not.

Comment: You can also use the `after()` method which is probably what you need. 
 [link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#afterdurationmilliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations

> Time-driven triggers cannot run more frequently than once per hour.

---

**Edit:** [Sandy Good's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946873/sandy-good) comment show you how to runs more precise timer based on miliseconds:

> You can also use the after() method which is probably what you need. [link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#afterdurationmilliseconds)

*Remember that **all timers** run at +/- 15 minutes too.*